# My input field is hearing every "keydown" event but the enter. I have a datepicker on it and am unsure whats going on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form that accepts dates from datepicker or you can input your own date by hand.  I'm formatting any input date to match mm/dd/yyyy.  I'm doing that off the blur but I ran into a problem that when I hit enter to run search right away the input doesn't get formatted correctly thus throwing error.  If I hit enter the date picker goes away.  If I hit enter again then the input field hears it.  The input field though will hear every other keydown while date picker is visible.

```
        var $callSearchEndDate = $j('#call-search-end-date');
        $callSearchEndDate.datepicker();
        $callSearchEndDate.blur(function() {
            if (!utility.isNotEmpty($callSearchEndDate.val())) {
                $callSearchEndDate.datepicker('setDate', new Date());
            }
            $j(this).val(checkDate($j(this).val()));
        }).bind('keypress', function(e){
             var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
             console.log('key code = ' + code);
             if(code === 13) { 
                 $j(this).val(checkDate($j(this).val()));
             }
        });
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ Has it's own event you should bind to for close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer.  The date picker has its own event listening for when it closes.  Thanks @TheZ

```
// Call Search "End Date" datepicker
        var $callSearchEndDate = $j('#call-search-end-date');
        $callSearchEndDate.datepicker({
            onClose : function(){
                $j(this).val(checkDate($j(this).val()));
            }
        });
        $callSearchEndDate.blur(function() {
            if (!utility.isNotEmpty($callSearchEndDate.val())) {
                $callSearchEndDate.datepicker('setDate', new Date());
            }
            $j(this).val(checkDate($j(this).val()));
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to figure it out and then sharing your solution for others to see :)